# Bar plot with log scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've run into an interesting problem with scaling using ggplot. I have a dataset that I can graph just fine using the default linear scale but when I use scale_y_log10() the numbers go way off. Here is some example code and two pictures. Note that the max value in the linear scale is ~700 while the log scaling results in a value of 10^8. I show you that the entire dataset is only ~8000 entries long so something is not right.

I imagine the problem has something to do with the structure of my dataset and the binning as I cannot replicate this error on a common dataset like 'diamonds.' However I am not sure the best way to troubleshoot.

thanks,
zach cp

---

Edit: bdamarest can reproduce the scale problem on the diamond dataset like this:

```
example_1 = ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar() + scale_y_log10(); print(example_1)
```

---

```
#data.melt is the name of my dataset    
> ggplot(data.melt, aes(name, fill= Library)) + geom_bar()  
> ggplot(data.melt, aes(name, fill= Library)) + geom_bar()  + scale_y_log10()
> length(data.melt$name)
[1] 8003
```

[image: linear scale]
[image: log scale]

here is some example data... and I think I see the problem. The original melted dataset may have been ~10^8 rows long. Maybe the row numbers are being used for the stats?

```
> head(data.melt)
       Library         name               group
221938      AB Arthrofactin        glycopeptide
235087      AB   Putisolvin      cyclic peptide
235090      AB   Putisolvin      cyclic peptide
222125      AB Arthrofactin        glycopeptide
311468      AB     Triostin cyclic depsipeptide
92249       AB          CDA         lipopeptide
```

```
test2 <- data.frame(
  Library = rep("AB", 6L),
  name = c(
    "Arthrofactin", "Putisolvin", "Putisolvin", "Arthrofactin",
    "Triostin", "CDA"
  ),
  group = c(
    "glycopeptide", "cyclic peptide", "cyclic peptide", "glycopeptide",
    "cyclic depsipeptide", "lipopeptide"
  ),
  row.names = c(221938L, 235087L, 235090L, 222125L, 311468L, 92249L)
)
```

---

UPDATE:

Row numbers are not the issue. Here is the same data graphed using the same aes x-axis and fill color and the scaling is entirely correct:

```
> ggplot(data.melt, aes(name, fill= name)) + geom_bar()
> ggplot(data.melt, aes(name, fill= name)) + geom_bar() + scale_y_log10()
> length(data.melt$name)
[1] 8003
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible workaround in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340491/deal-with-bar-size-and-totals-when-ggplot-position-stack-in-split-charts/61806020#61806020

Comment: As a design logic, it is a bad practice to plot bars on a logscale. This is because bars/lines naturally incline people to compare their lengths, but they lose meaning when the scale is not linear, starting at 0 and lead to misleading interpretations. And in a logscale, the only meaningful portion of the bar is the location of its top - so might as well replace it with a point and make a dot-plot right? 

Don't use logscale on a barplot - https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/graph-tip-dont-use-a-log-scale-on-a-bar-graph/
use dotplots - http://perceptualedge.com/articles/b-eye/dot_plots.pdf)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`geom_bar` and `scale_y_log10` (or any logarithmic scale) do not work well together and do not give expected results.

The first fundamental problem is that bars go to 0, and on a logarithmic scale, 0 is transformed to negative infinity (which is hard to plot). The crib around this usually to start at 1 rather than 0 (since $\log(1)=0$), not plot anything if there were 0 counts, and not worry about the distortion because if a log scale is needed you probably don't care about being off by 1 (not necessarily true, but...)

I'm using the `diamonds` example that @dbemarest showed.

To do this in general is to transform the coordinate, not the scale (more on the difference later).

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_trans(ytrans="log10")
```

But this gives an error

```
Error in if (length(from) == 1 || abs(from[1] - from[2]) < 1e-06) return(mean(to)) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

which arises from the negative infinity problem.

When you use a scale transformation, the transformation is applied to the data, then stats and arrangements are made, then the scales are labeled in the inverse transformation (roughly).  You can see what is happening by breaking out the calculations yourself.

```
DF <- ddply(diamonds, .(clarity, cut), summarise, n=length(clarity))
DF$log10n <- log10(DF$n)
```

which gives

```
> head(DF)
  clarity       cut   n   log10n
1      I1      Fair 210 2.322219
2      I1      Good  96 1.982271
3      I1 Very Good  84 1.924279
4      I1   Premium 205 2.311754
5      I1     Ideal 146 2.164353
6     SI2      Fair 466 2.668386
```

If we plot this in the normal way, we get the expected bar plot:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=clarity, y=n, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

and scaling the y axis gives the same problem as using the not pre-summarized data.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=clarity, y=n, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

We can see how the problem happens by plotting the `log10()` values of the counts.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=clarity, y=log10n, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

This looks just like the one with the `scale_y_log10`, but the labels are 0, 5, 10, ... instead of 10^0, 10^5, 10^10, ...

So using `scale_y_log10` makes the counts, converts them to logs, stacks those logs, and then displays the scale in the anti-log form. Stacking logs, however, is not a linear transformation, so what you have asked it to do does not make any sense.

The bottom line is that stacked bar charts on a log scale don't make much sense because they can't start at 0 (where the bottom of a bar should be), and comparing parts of the bar is not reasonable because their size depends on where they are in the stack. Considered instead something like:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, y=..count.., colour=cut)) + 
  geom_point(stat="bin") +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Or if you really want a total for the groups that stacking the bars usually would give you, you can do something like:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, y=..count..)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=cut), stat="bin") +
  geom_point(stat="bin", colour="black") +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Brian, I appreciate you detailed explanation.  You can also use  geom_bar(position="dodge") (answer courtesy of Winston Chang)

Comment: To give a little more insight on what's happening here, stacked bar charts typically give you a bar height equal to the sum of counts. However, sum(log(counts)) is equivalent to log(product(counts)). In other words, you'll see bar heights as if you multiplied the counts together.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to get rid of the `bar` stacking (as @Brian commented `log(sum(x)) != sum(log(x))`) by using `facet_wrap`. You could also add a panel to represent the `Total` if needed.

For instance, for the `diamonds` dataset (following @Brian Diggs's answer), we could either plot

```
diamonds %>%
  bind_rows(                                                  # Adds a
    diamonds %>%                                              # panel to 
    mutate(cut = "Total")                                     # represent
  ) %>%                                                       # the
  mutate(cut = cut %>% fct_relevel("Total", after = Inf)) %>% # Total
  ggplot(aes(x = clarity, fill = clarity)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~cut) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image: clarity]

or,

```
diamonds %>%
  bind_rows(                                                          # Adds a
    diamonds %>%                                                      # panel to
    mutate(clarity = "Total")                                         # represent
  ) %>%                                                               # the
  mutate(clarity = clarity %>% fct_relevel("Total", after = Inf)) %>% # Total
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~clarity) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image: cut]