# Why does the value of y increase in geom_bar(stat = "identity") for a stacked bar chart with a factor grouping?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following example, I think the height of the bars should be 500 and 45.  Why are they both over 1000?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  grp = factor(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2), levels = 0:2),
  y = c(200, 300, 25, 15, 5)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = grp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image: bad_plot]

If you use `position = "dodge"`, the y-axis values appear to be correct.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = grp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::comma)
```

[image: good_plot]

Any ideas where `ggplot2` is getting its y-axis values in the first plot?

Comment: It looks like [this github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3671) is about something very similar.

Comment: You expect the bar to give you the sum of the counts. But with the log transformation, you're actually getting the product of the counts. I find the accepted answer to this post -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580937/ggplots-scale-y-log10-behavior -- to be very useful here.

Comment: And some suggested alternatives to `geom_bar` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502003/ggplot-scale-y-log10-issue/9507037#9507037.

Comment: Thank you!  This is extremely helpful.  It looks like the key issue is that logging the axis means that the top bar of the stack will look much shorter than the bottom bar, even if they represent the same value.  ggplot gives the product, which makes the area look roughly correct, but makes the y axis very wrong.  You can get around that with `coord_trans(y = "log1p")`.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen this, and if @aosmith or @AHart want to add an answer that mentions the elements in the comments -- namely: (1) the code in the question is giving you the product, (2) `coord_trans()` gives a workaround, and (3) `coord_trans()` produces a weird scaling of the bars, which is probably why `scale_y_log10()` doesn't work in the first place -- I'll accept it as an answer.