# ggplot geom_bar with scale_y_log10 originates at 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a logscaled, neighbored, barplot with ggplot().

**Code snippet:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(benchmarks, runtime, fill=env))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
scale_y_log10()
```

**Output:**

[image: ggplot]

The boxes' origin is at '1', but I want them at '0.01', much like this barplot:

[image: barplot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using a log scale for a bar plot :) There are good reasons not to do so, explained very well [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502003/ggplot-scale-y-log10-issue).

Comment: You can use `geom_rect` instead of `geom_bar` and set all the minima to 0.01 instead of 0. But I'd agree with neilfws that log-scaled barplots are terrible.

Comment: I did a bad search job there. Thank you for your answers, I will not use geom_bar with scale_y_log10 anymore.