# How to to assign logarithmic scale to “Intersection size” using ComplexUpset library?

Tags: r, upsetplot, complex-upset

When I assigning a  logarithmic scale to “Intersection size” using ComplexUpset library the bars disappear. Is there a way around?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you need answers, you have to provide us with all the information needed to understand the problem. Please give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is because in ggplot2's `geom_bar` does not play well with log10 scale/transform when using stat other than `"identity"` (see [Bar plot with log scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502003/bar-plot-with-log-scales)). `CompelxUpset` plots each data point individually to allow for colouring each observation separately. You can revert to plotting pre-summarised data by passing the following function as data to `geom_bar`:

```
presence = ComplexUpset:::get_mode_presence('exclusive_intersection')

summarise_values = function(df) {
    aggregate(
        as.formula(paste0(presence, '~ intersection')),
        df,
        FUN=sum
    )
}
```

and then plot it, starting with the example:

```
library(ComplexUpset)
library(ggplot2)
movies = as.data.frame(ggplot2movies::movies)
movies[movies$mpaa == '', 'mpaa'] = NA
movies = na.omit(movies)
genres = colnames(movies)[18:24]
```

to get log10 transform only:

```
upset(
    movies,
    genres,
    base_annotations=list(
        'log10(intersection size)'=(
            ggplot()
            + geom_bar(data=summarise_values, stat='identity', aes(y=!!presence))
            + ylab('Intersection size')
            + scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
        )
    ),
    min_size=5,
    width_ratio=0.1
)
```

[image]

to get log10 on axis too:

```
upset(
    movies,
    genres,
    base_annotations=list(
        'log10(intersection size)'=(
            ggplot()
            + geom_bar(
                data=summarise_values,
                stat='identity',
                aes(y=log10(!!presence))
            )
            + ylab('log10(intersection size)')
        )
    ),
    width_ratio=0.1
)
```

[image]